# setValue: forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization" does not work

Tags: http-headers, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to connect to a server which requires a username and password for Authentication. My code is the following:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"username:password" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

But this does not work, I always get an error message:

```
title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
```

When I try to connect to a server which doesn't nee an Authentication this code code works great. So, how to set the username and password correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the domain of server, try this format:

```
NSString *authen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\\%@:%@", m_domain,
        m_account, m_password];
[request setValue:authen forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

this work for me!